# Possible bug in GridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am encountering what I suspect may be a bug in the Androids `GridLayoutManager`. I have a simple setup: a `RecyclerView` with that uses a `GridLayoutManager` with a `SpanSizeLookup` (Code below). The number of columns used in the layout manager is variable; determined by screen size and screen orientation.

I initialise my layout manager as follows:

```
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),
                   getResources().getInteger(R.integer.products_per_row));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

And my `SpanSizeLookup` uses the following `getSpanSize` method

```
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? 
            getResources().getInteger(R.integer.products_per_row)) : 1;
    }
```

Android everything works as expected: when the screen is rotated the number of columns changes accordingly with no crashes. However if the screen is in portrait and the user starts an activity (eg. by opening an app from a notification) that forces it's orientation to landscape I get the following crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Item at position 0 requires 2 spans but GridLayoutManager has only 1 spans.
   at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:430)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
   at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14565)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4473)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2185)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1999)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1212)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4981)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

For absolute clarity: R.integer.products_per_row is 1 for "normal" screen size devices in portrait and 2 in landscape in this case.

Now I fully accept that this might be a fault in my code however I fail to see what I could be doing wrong here.

Comment: setting span size of the gridLayoutManager seems to solve the problem.